# how to get JS links from a website

Tags: javascript, html, dom, phantomjs, web-crawler

I have to get some URLs of a website, but there not existing as typical `<a href="">` links.

I have already found out with phantomJS to crawl some JS contents and ajax results etc.

but I can't find out how to get a list of links to a page while I am crawling this page...

Here is the structure of the content:

[image]

I have already tried out to catch it with php's file_get_content() and the normal phantomJS() request but nothing helped me :(

could you please give me a hint?

Comment: *"but there not existing as typical links"* OK, that tells us what they're not. Maybe now tell us what they *are*.

Comment: Yes, you cannot find any URLs because the whole control of the page is under JavaScript click events. Just have a look how is created Id in tr. It consists from prefix and some unique string Id. If I can advice you something lets try to find and look into js files.

Comment: You're looking for CSS Selector Syntax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) or XPath (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)

Comment: @spanky: ok sorry for that: but they are nothing as blank text... and I think somehere deep in some js code blocks there are maybe some ajax onclick functions which includes the real links...

or maybe they are generating the links from this id="xxx" and they getting the links from a DB with this id="xxx" sorry i dont know it exactly...

thats my problem.... -.-

Comment: @ArturPoniedziałek: ok thx for this hint, I will give it a try, but there sooo many js files :(

Comment: @lxe: hey also thank you! but i knot the css selectors :) I just want to know if maybe could read the page into a new DOM, and pulling then the links but the DOM Tree of this page also dont includes links... only asynchron. things which are generating then the reall onclick event / Link ( maybe )

but thx for all of your comments!

Comment: Can you send link to the website?

Answer (score 1):

look first in your inline  tags for JS redirects.  If that fails, look in your header for anything inside of  tags like this:

```
<script async="" src="https://SOME-URL"></script>
```

If you copy those URLs into your browser you can get the plain text of the JS files.  You can then search them for JavaScript redirect behaviors as well.

Comment: ok let me try that.... but when the page has some things like jquery onclick functions, it will be hard to find it in all of these js extensions

Comment: sorry but there are no "<script async" elements in the source code

Comment: it is probably inline JS or they intentionally obfuscated it using basecodeing.  Do you have a URL to this website?